# tool to extract data structures from unclean data

Tags: parsing, data-structures, data-modeling, data-cleaning

I have unstructured geneally unclean data in a database field. There are common structures which are consistent in the data

namely:

```
field:

name:value 

fieldset: 

nombre <FieldSet>
field,
  .
  .
  .
field(n)

table

nombre <table>
head(1)... head(n)
val(1)...  val(n)
      .
      .
      .
```

I was wondering if there was a tool (preferably in Java) that could extract learn/understand these data structures, parse the file and convert to a Map or object which I could run validation checks on?

I am aware of Antlr but understand this is more geared towards tree construction, an not independent bits of data (am I wrong about this?)

Does anyone have any suggestions for the problem as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Talend](http://www.talend.com). It is very versatile, open source data integration tool. It is based on java. You can use build in tools/components to extract data from unstructured data sources. You can also write complex custom java code to do what you want.

I used Talend in couple of scientific proof of concept projects of mine. It worked for me. Good part is, it is free!

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using antlr for this, it required us to make multiple lexers where one lexer would manipulated the input for the next lexer.

Another project is [pads](http://www.padsproj.org/) - wrote in C

Answer (score 0):

You should use "bnflite"
https://github.com/r35382/bnflite
Using this template library you need to develop BNF like gramma for your text by means of classes and overloaded operators directly in C++ code.
The benefit is that such gramma is easily adjustable to your source