# in ANTLR What do the auto generated DFA strings, such as eotS, eofS, acceptS mean and how are they generated

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, lex, antlr3, dfa

When I generate a lexer with antlr from a grammer file I notice it generates a series of strings in hex format.

These strings are utilised by the DFA to predict what tokens my be next.

What do these strings mean and how are they generated.

the strings I am referreing to appear in the generated lexer like this (aand are passed to the DFA in the constructor):

```
static final String DFA1_eotS = ....

static final String DFA1_eofS = ....

static final String DFA1_minS = ....

static final String DFA1_maxS = ....

static final String DFA1_acceptS = ....

static final String DFA1_specialS = ....                                                

static final String[] DFA1_transitionS = ....
```

Edit:

I will begin answering by own question to get us started

acceptS[i] = an array containing an identifier for possible tokens (I don't know why it contains many -1 values)

Comment: Not sure what strings you mean exactly, but do you ask just out of curiosity, or are you trying to solve an actual problem?

Comment: I did submit the strings in an edit yesterday but they didn't show up, I am trying again but it is still failing (page requested not found).

Comment: But, do you ask just out of curiosity, or are you trying to solve an actual problem?

Comment: @Bart Kiers - sorry I had more to that response but for some reason sof keeps locking me out of this question

Comment: @Bart Kiers - I am looking at creating a DFA for antlr which uses the levenshtein distribution to predict tokens because I can't guarantee all my tokens will be spelt correctly. Have you any suggestions for this? I had this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465374/tool-to-extract-data-structures-from-unclean-data from last week (Prob doesn't help) but I was making some nice progress with a solution involving antlr

Comment: @Bart Kiers - I finally got the edit in but had to omit a certain string which was causing problems, see question again and answer

Comment: No, I've not used ANTLR in that way, and can therefor not help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DFA_minS, DFA_maxS** I think refers to range of chars it can fall between as it moves through the state table

**DFA_transitionS**. I think is the state table

**DFA_specialsS** I think is something to do with adding the semanticet predicates to the rules and

**DFA_acceptS** seems to be the set of case values in a switch specifying which token is being accepted by the DFA

Note: I still would like to know if these are correct and how they are generated